# Как обрезать/удалить часть изображения

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pygame

Подскажите статью, видео или код, чтобы осуществить задуманное на гифке. По сути есть шарик, который движется вертикально и горизонтально, нажатием кнопки W/S-вверх, вниз A/D- влево, вправо и два изображения (белый) и поверх него (зеленый). При замыкание, должно происходить удаление выделенной части.
[image]

Comment: а как определяется выделенная часть? что надо удалить если разделить прямоугольник пополам?

Comment: наверное это подойдёт https://younglinux.info/pygame/surface

Comment: Да это ж Xonix! ))

Comment: @timur Там ещё враги должны быть, заполняется та часть, которая без врагов )  Автор до эмуляции врагов видимо не дошёл ещё